# How to increase the line-spacing in the title?

Tags: fonts, titles, line-spacing, helvetica

I want to increase the line spacing in the title of my thesis.

[image: example title]

Here's the Latex code:

```
{\fontsize{25}{25}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{bc}{n}\selectfont\par
This is a very long title and I want to increase the spacing beetween the two lines}
\par
```

I tried using `\linespread{1.5}` but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: If you are using a university provided document class or template, I wouldn't mess with it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to (a) increase the leading (your setting has *zero leading*) and place the `\par` directive before rather than after the final `}` curly brace.

The following screenshot shows the difference between 0pt, 5pt, and 10pt of leading. (The horizontal lines are there just to indicate the vertical extent of the title material.) What the "right" amount of leading may be for your document is something that only you can decide.

Incidentally, why do you impose the `OT1` font encoding? I'd heartily recommend going with the `T1` encoding.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\centering

% OP's code (zero leading)
\hrule
{\fontsize{25}{25}\usefont{T1}{phv}{bc}{n}\selectfont\par
This is a very long title and I want to increase the spacing between the two lines}\par
\hrule

% 5pt leading
\bigskip  
\hrule 
{\fontsize{25}{30}\usefont{T1}{phv}{bc}{n}\selectfont\par
This is a very long title and I want to increase the spacing between the two lines\par}
\hrule

% 10pt leading
\bigskip
\hrule
{\fontsize{25}{35}\usefont{T1}{phv}{bc}{n}\selectfont\par
This is a very long title and I want to increase the spacing between the two lines\par}
\hrule
\end{document}
```